# save cloudwatch logs generated by glue crawler in another cloudwatch log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

is there a way of saving logs generated by a crawler in a specific, newly created cloudwatch log group?

I want to use the finish crawling log as a trigger to a lambda function.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution for that in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS CloudWatch Logs API to upload logs. Use [`CreateLogGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogGroup.html) and [`CreateLogStream`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogStream.html) to create your log stream, and then use [`PutLogEvents`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html) to upload your log.

There are other options that might be more suitable for triggering a Lambda function though, depending on your exact use case, such as uploading the collected log to S3 and having the upload trigger the function, or even starting the Lambda function directly.